# How to overcome batch file execution part way through when using CFExecute with PsExec to run Git actions?

Tags: git, batch-file, coldfusion, psexec, cfexecute

I’m encountering a weird issue and have tried many different things.

The goal is to have a user click a button on a web page that will execute a batch file on several other servers.

I am using ColdFusion 8. When the user clicks the button, CFExecute launches PSExec.exe to execute the file on remote machine.

excerpt from bat file

```
cd c:\web\www >> \\firstmachine\c$\web\qa\html\RA\ra.log
git pull origin master >> \\firstmachine\c$\web\qa\html\RA\ra.log

cd c:\web\aaa >> \\firstmachine\c$\web\qa\html\RA\ra.log
git pull origin master >> \\firstmachine\c$\web\qa\html\RA\ra.log
```

---

When I run it from a command prompt git runs properly and does a pull from www and aaa. Log file shows everything worked as expected.

```
c:\web\qa\html\RA\PsExec.exe \\othermachine -u domain\adminaccount -p <password> c:\web\qa\html\RA\script.bat
```

When I run the same command from CF using CFExecute, git only does a pull on www and not aaa.

```
<cfexecute name="c:\web\qa\html\RA\PsExec.exe" 
       variable="var" arguments="\\othermachine -u 
       domain\adminaccount -p <password> c:\web\qa\html\RA\script.bat" 
       timeout="50"> 
</cfexecute>
```

If I swap the lines around, git does a pull on aaa and not www.
In these cases the log file shows nothing after the first successful pull, as if the process aborted, but I can not find anything else out of the ordinary.

Any thoughts are much appreciated!

Comment: have you tried adding a requesttimeout to make sure your giving it enough time without coldfusion timing out the request?

   <cfsetting requesttimeout="300">

Comment: What happens if you run one in a separate thread?

Comment: @steve I have not set a timeout, but the script runs fast. The coldFusion page returns in just a few seconds. Running from the command line works and still takes less than 10 seconds.

Comment: If you output some text after each cfexecute tag, do both strings show up?

Comment: I know this sounds like the lazy answer, but if you make a 2nd batch file for your other call and call it through cfexecute after the first one runs, would that work?

Comment: @DanBracuk both strings show up. This may work, but so far it's flaky. Need more testing. Thanks, will let you know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up taking out the batch file and using a separate CFExecute command for each action.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use CALL command and have both blocks in separate labels. When you run batch file from outside programs, you need to specify exit /b [error_code]. What probably happens if batch executes first git pull and returns success code to what has called it. The structure below will only send it after it successfully executes both parts.

```
SET _err_lvl=0
CALL :pull_www
CALL :pull_aaa

IF %_err_lvl% EQU 0 exit /b 0

:pull_www
cd c:\web\www >> \\firstmachine\c$\web\qa\html\RA\ra.log
git pull origin master >> \\firstmachine\c$\web\qa\html\RA\ra.log
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 SET _err_lvl=1
:end_pull_www
GOTO: eof

:pull_aaa
cd c:\web\aaa >> \\firstmachine\c$\web\qa\html\RA\ra.log
git pull origin master >> \\firstmachine\c$\web\qa\html\RA\ra.log
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 SET _err_lvl=1
:end_pull_aaa
GOTO: eof
```